# Cross-module EMMA coverage in Maven

Tags: maven, code-coverage, emma

I'm unfortunately very unfamiliar with both Maven and EMMA. As such, searching this site and Google has yielded results where I'm not completely certain if they apply to my situation, and even if so, how to actually do it in practice.

I have a system in module A, but due to various reasons, the test code for said system must be located in module B. Unfortunately, EMMA seems to check for coverage on a per-module basis, in that when running test cases in module B, module A doesn't seem to be instrumented. As such, when reports A and B are merged, it leaves large sections of module A uncovered.

Now, my question is two-fold:

- Is it possible to run EMMA in such a way that all modules are instrumented, allowing module B's test cases to cover module A?
- If so, how would one go about configuring the Maven POM file to do this instead of the default behavior?